# how to count number of tables/views/index in my database

Tags: sybase

how to count number of tables/views/index in my database

I am using sybase 11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select count(*) from sysobjects where type = 'U'
```

should get you the number of user tables. You can also use `type = 'V'` to count views.

```
select count(*) from sysindexes
```

will give you an index count. You may need to further filter both though, depending on which types of indexes you want.

sysobjects reference [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables46.htm). 
sysindexes reference [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables46.htm).

Answer (score 0):

For oracle

Count Tables:

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables;**

Count Sequences

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_sequences;**

Count Views

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_views;**

Count Indexes

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_indexes;**

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES;
```

will return you number of tables in respective database.

Comment: for mysql, this query seems work well for single database,
`SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'base table' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATA_BASE_NAME';`